# How do I resolve url_launcher issues with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, url-launcher

I consistently get errors when I try to debug my app using an Android emulator, getting the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\PC\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.13.3-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 16s
>
> Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried creating a new flutter project and transferring the details over multiple times to no avail. I have tried updating the url_launcher package, and individually installing url_launcher_windows (it seems to be included in url_launcher anyway). Here is the relevant part of my pubspec.yaml file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.9
  firebase_ui_auth: ^1.13.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  firebase_ui_oauth_google: ^1.3.1
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  url_launcher_windows: ^3.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  shadcn_ui: ^0.2.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```